# Напиши функции которые с помощью перебирающих методов массива (без for, splice и т. д.) выполняют операции над массивом объектов пользователей

Tags: javascript

```
users = [
{
    id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
    name: 'Moore Hensley',
    email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 37,
},
{
    id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
    name: 'Sharlene Bush',
    email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 34,
},
{
    id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
    name: 'Ross Vazquez',
    email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 24,
},
{
    id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
    name: 'Elma Head',
    email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
    eyeColor: 'green',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 21,
},
{
    id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
    name: 'Carey Barr',
    email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
    eyeColor: 'blue',
    friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 27,
},
{
    id: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
    name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
    email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
    gender: 'male',
    age: 38,
},
{
    id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
    name: 'Sheree Anthony',
    email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
    eyeColor: 'brown',
    friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
    gender: 'female',
    age: 39,
},
```

];

Вот мой код, не пойму в чём дело, если можно описать решение декларативным и императивным способом

```
const getUsersWithFriend = (users, friendName) => {
let arrNew = [];
const checkOut = function (arr, el) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i] === el) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
for (let i = 0; i <= users.length; i++) {
    if (checkOut(users[i].friends, friendName)) {
        arrNew.push(users[i].name);
    }
}
return arrNew;
```

};

console.log(getUsersWithFriend(users, 'Briana Decker')); // [ 'Sharlene Bush', 'Sheree Anthony' ]
console.log(getUsersWithFriend(users, 'Goldie Gentry')); // [ 'Elma Head', 'Sheree Anthony' ]

Answer (score 0):

Для начала ваш Код. Чтоб работал

```js
let users = [
  {
      id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
      name: 'Moore Hensley',
      email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
      eyeColor: 'blue',
      friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
      isActive: false,
      balance: 2811,
      skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
      gender: 'male',
      age: 37,
  },
  {
      id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
      name: 'Sharlene Bush',
      email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
      eyeColor: 'blue',
      friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
      isActive: true,
      balance: 3821,
      skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
      gender: 'female',
      age: 34,
  },
  {
      id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
      name: 'Ross Vazquez',
      email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
      eyeColor: 'green',
      friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
      isActive: false,
      balance: 3793,
      skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
      gender: 'male',
      age: 24,
  },
  {
      id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
      name: 'Elma Head',
      email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
      eyeColor: 'green',
      friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
      isActive: true,
      balance: 2278,
      skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
      gender: 'female',
      age: 21,
  },
  {
      id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
      name: 'Carey Barr',
      email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
      eyeColor: 'blue',
      friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
      isActive: true,
      balance: 3951,
      skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
      gender: 'male',
      age: 27,
  },
  {
      id: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
      name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
      email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
      eyeColor: 'brown',
      friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
      isActive: false,
      balance: 1498,
      skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
      gender: 'male',
      age: 38,
  },
  {
      id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
      name: 'Sheree Anthony',
      email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
      eyeColor: 'brown',
      friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
      isActive: true,
      balance: 2764,
      skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
      gender: 'female',
      age: 39,
  }
];


const getUsersWithFriend = (users, friendName) => {
  let arrNew = [];
  const checkOut = function (arr, el) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
          if (arr[j] === el) {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      if (checkOut(users[i].friends, friendName)) {
          arrNew.push(users[i].name);
      }
  }
  return arrNew;
};

console.log(getUsersWithFriend(users, 'Briana Decker')); // [ 'Sharlene Bush', 'Sheree Anthony' ] 
console.log(getUsersWithFriend(users, 'Goldie Gentry')); // [ 'Elma Head', 'Sheree Anthony' ]
```

2. ну и в императивном ваша функция `getUsersWithFriend` выраждается в строчку

`const getUsersWithFriend = (users, friendName) => users.filter(item=>item.friends.includes(friendName)).map(item=>item.name);`

```js
let users = [
  {
      id: '701b29c3-b35d-4cf1-a5f6-8b12b29a5081',
      name: 'Moore Hensley',
      email: 'moorehensley@indexia.com',
      eyeColor: 'blue',
      friends: ['Sharron Pace'],
      isActive: false,
      balance: 2811,
      skills: ['ipsum', 'lorem'],
      gender: 'male',
      age: 37,
  },
  {
      id: '7a3cbd18-57a1-4534-8e12-1caad921bda1',
      name: 'Sharlene Bush',
      email: 'sharlenebush@tubesys.com',
      eyeColor: 'blue',
      friends: ['Briana Decker', 'Sharron Pace'],
      isActive: true,
      balance: 3821,
      skills: ['tempor', 'mollit', 'commodo', 'veniam', 'laborum'],
      gender: 'female',
      age: 34,
  },
  {
      id: '88beb2f3-e4c2-49f3-a0a0-ecf957a95af3',
      name: 'Ross Vazquez',
      email: 'rossvazquez@xinware.com',
      eyeColor: 'green',
      friends: ['Marilyn Mcintosh', 'Padilla Garrison', 'Naomi Buckner'],
      isActive: false,
      balance: 3793,
      skills: ['nulla', 'anim', 'proident', 'ipsum', 'elit'],
      gender: 'male',
      age: 24,
  },
  {
      id: '249b6175-5c30-44c6-b154-f120923736f5',
      name: 'Elma Head',
      email: 'elmahead@omatom.com',
      eyeColor: 'green',
      friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Aisha Tran'],
      isActive: true,
      balance: 2278,
      skills: ['adipisicing', 'irure', 'velit'],
      gender: 'female',
      age: 21,
  },
  {
      id: '334f8cb3-eb04-45e6-abf4-4935dd439b70',
      name: 'Carey Barr',
      email: 'careybarr@nurali.com',
      eyeColor: 'blue',
      friends: ['Jordan Sampson', 'Eddie Strong'],
      isActive: true,
      balance: 3951,
      skills: ['ex', 'culpa', 'nostrud'],
      gender: 'male',
      age: 27,
  },
  {
      id: '150b00fb-dd82-427d-9faf-2879ea87c695',
      name: 'Blackburn Dotson',
      email: 'blackburndotson@furnigeer.com',
      eyeColor: 'brown',
      friends: ['Jacklyn Lucas', 'Linda Chapman'],
      isActive: false,
      balance: 1498,
      skills: ['non', 'amet', 'ipsum'],
      gender: 'male',
      age: 38,
  },
  {
      id: 'e1bf46ab-7168-491e-925e-f01e21394812',
      name: 'Sheree Anthony',
      email: 'shereeanthony@kog.com',
      eyeColor: 'brown',
      friends: ['Goldie Gentry', 'Briana Decker'],
      isActive: true,
      balance: 2764,
      skills: ['lorem', 'veniam', 'culpa'],
      gender: 'female',
      age: 39,
  }
];


const getUsersWithFriend = (users, friendName) => users.filter(item=>item.friends.includes(friendName)).map(item=>item.name);

console.log(getUsersWithFriend(users, 'Briana Decker')); // [ 'Sharlene Bush', 'Sheree Anthony' ] 
console.log(getUsersWithFriend(users, 'Goldie Gentry')); // [ 'Elma Head', 'Sheree Anthony' ]
```